# OSX: which type of Daemon/Background Process should I use?

Tags: macos, daemon, background-process

I have a program I want to run on startup and wakeup from sleep. However, I found a resource on a number of different kinds of services which could be of use to me. I need a good answer on which kind of daemon/background service suits my purposes best. Here is an outline of some details about my program:

1) it will launch automatically, in the background (aka without the user being aware of it) when the computer is either woken up from sleep, restarted, or started up from a shutdown-state.

2) The program will operate separately for each user. The files that are created as a result of the program's operation will need to be separate for each user.

I found a good resource at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/DesigningDaemons.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW4-BBCBHBFB but I am unsure which to use: login item, XPC Service, Launch Daemon, or Launch Agent.

Comment: I DO need a UI for settings and configuration, but I do NOT need a UI for the scripts that will run on startup and wakeup. 

well to be honest, I will need to be able to edit settings and configuration of the scripts managed by the daemon/process, and upon learning more I might find a use for using a UI directly associated with the Daemon/process. I would likely want to be able to edit D/P settings associated with each user if possible.

In addition to that, I will need a UI to manage settings for the program as installed for the current user, but I believe I can just use Java to do that.

Comment: Does the process need to run even if the user hasn't logged in yet?

Comment: I believe if your daemon needs to present a UI a Login Item is basically the only choice.

Answer (score 1):

> 2) The program will operate separately for each user. The files that are created as a result of the program's operation will need to be separate for each user.

This strongly suggests using a LaunchAgent, since those are per-user (and run as the user).

The page you'll probably want is the [launchd.plist](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/5/launchd.plist) man page.

I'm not aware of a launchd trigger that matches your request, which unfortunately may mean you need to run with the `KeepAlive` option and monitor for power changes.

You will catch login (though not boot, since that's not "per user") at the point that you launch, so that's easy. Sleep and powerdown are pretty easily managed through Cocoa and `NSWorkspace` by observing notifications like 
`NSWorkspaceWillPowerOffNotification` and 
`NSWorkspaceWillSleepNotification`. If Cocoa is too high-level for your problem, you can hook into IOKit power management events. See [Managing Power](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/IOKitFundamentals/PowerMgmt/PowerMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP0000020-SW8) in IOKit Fundamentals for a good low-level introduction.

Note that there is a "kind of awake but not really" state called DarkWake, which can confuse you depending on your needs. The 2012 WWDC Video on [Power Management](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=711) is a good introduction to this issue.